# Importing multiple GPX files without selecting waypoints/tracks/... for each file separately using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, gpx

I've got several GPX files.

I'd like to import them into a QGIS project.

If I'm going with `>add Vectorlayer` QGIS asks one for **each** file, which specific parts (waypoints/tracks/...) to load.

I'm looking for a better option.

Comment: are you already [check this](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html#loading-gps-data-from-a-file)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but my impression is: With GPS-Tools it is only possible to import **one** GPX file at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could batch convert them with gdal to shp, either in python or on the command line and then open the result.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!
I discovered something similar: With GPSBabel it is possible to load many GPX files and store them in one single GPX file. And it is possible to load this big file in QGIS.

Comment: That would do it! Hopefully you've found a way to wrap it all in a script to complete the process in the future.